# Why can't I run javac and java commands through docker-compose.yml

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, javac

I am trying to use command: javac -cp "/src/java" Program.java && java -cp "/src/java" Program in my docker-compose.yml file to build and run a java program that outputs some text upon starting my container but I get an error that states the java file cannot be found.

I have tried various forms of command: javac -cp "/src/java" Program.java && java -cp "/src/java" Program such as:

- command: `javac Program.java && java Program`
- command: `["javac", "Program.java"] && ["java", "Program"]`
- command: `javac /jonolson/Program.java && java Program`
- command: `javac jonolson/Program.java && java jonolson/Program`
  but nothing is working.
  right now my docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
services:
  my-java-app:
    image: openjdk:19
    working_dir: /src/java
    command: javac -cp "/src/java" Program.java && java -cp "/src/java" Program
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: jonolson
        target: /src/java
```

and I get this error message when I run docker-compose up in command line:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong. I needed to run the javac and java commands as a shell script so the solution is using:

command: sh -c "javac Program.java && java Program"

for my command line.

Comment: I also realized that my source: in my bind mount needed to be ./ instead of jonolson

Comment: Actually in Java 11 up you can compile AND run a _single_ source file with the command `java Program.java` (no `javac` and no `&&`) -- if and only if `Program.java` is in the working directory, so actually your comment is necessary but your answer is not.